# How to load another database using CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a CodeIgniter and some Mysql database. But know I want to set the another database for working, and after some actions do disable it. For example, I have function make_some_actions_with_db(), and now I need to have something like that:

```
public function action()
{
//load db
make_some_actions_with_db();
//disable db
}
```

So, now I need to know how I can set the new default db and how I can set another (first) db. Thank you.

**UPDATED:**
It doesn't work:

```
   public function update_record_insert_test()
    {
        if ($this->facebook->getUser())
        {
            $another_db_settings['hostname'] = 'localhost';
            $another_db_settings['username'] = 'root';
            $another_db_settings['password'] = '';
            $another_db_settings['database'] = 'name';
            $another_db_settings['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
            $another_db_settings['dbprefix'] = "";
            $another_db_settings['pconnect'] = TRUE;
            $another_db_settings['db_debug'] = TRUE;
            $another_db_settings['cache_on'] = FALSE;
            $another_db_settings['cachedir'] = "";
            $another_db_settings['char_set'] = "utf8";
            $another_db_settings['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
            $this->load->database($another_db_settings);

            $_POST['id']='AccountPagesView.a_book/1000';
            $_POST['value']='test';
            $_POST['old_value']='not';
            $welcome=new Welcome();
            $welcome->update_record();
        }
        else
        {
            $url=$this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array('next' => base_url().'update_record_insert_test'));
            redirect($url);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

In your `config/database.php` your database is configured to the 'default' group, like so:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'host';
$db['default']['username'] = 'username';
$db['default']['password'] = 'password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database';
```

This allows you to specify other groups like this:

```
$db['second']['hostname'] = 'host';
$db['second']['username'] = 'username';
$db['second']['password'] = 'password';
$db['second']['database'] = 'database';

$db['third']['hostname'] = 'host';
$db['third']['username'] = 'username';
$db['third']['password'] = 'password';
$db['third']['database'] = 'database';
```

You can then connect to another database by using:

```
$defaultDB = $this->load->database('default', TRUE);
$secondDB = $this->load->database('second', TRUE);
```

By passing `true` as the second value, it will return the database object, allowing you to safely use the same methods for each database, like so:

```
$default->get('table');
$second->get('different_table');
```

Comment: Now I make all request using $this->db->get(...), and I can't change this code, but there is the same db with the same tables, I need to change the default db this this one. How I can do it? For example, now I have "db1" database, and the second is "db1_copy" - I need that all request similar $this->db->... will be executed with "db1_copy".

Comment: If you can change the config, change the details for the `default` group to the details of 'db1_copy'. That should work?

Comment: From what I'm understanding from this, are you setting up environments? Like development and production environments? In this case, why not place an IF statement in your database config file to detect which database config to use. Something like $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == 'something' => $active_group = 'db1'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default database connection (which I don't recommend) you can do :

```
$another_db_settings['hostname'] = '';
$another_db_settings['username'] = '';
$another_db_settings['password'] = '';
$another_db_settings['database'] = '';
$another_db_settings['dbdriver'] = "mysql";
$another_db_settings['dbprefix'] = "";
$another_db_settings['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$another_db_settings['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$another_db_settings['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$another_db_settings['cachedir'] = "";
$another_db_settings['char_set'] = "utf8";
$another_db_settings['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
$this->load->database($another_db_settings);
```

Then the new database can be accessed via $this->db, but I would recommend doing what cchana suggested and assign the new connection to another variable via

```
$new_db = $this->load->database($another_db_settings, TRUE);
```

Comment: Your recommendation doesn't work. Please check updated question.

Comment: Could you show the Welcome class? I don't see why you would need another database connection in this case.

Comment: update_record() function in Welcome class does some actions with main database. I need to test it, and I want to use for it copy of main db.